# How can I improve the speed for a fullscreen image background?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I´m using `Supersized jQuery` Plugin for my fullscreen image slider on my first page.

What can I do to improve speed, specially on mobile devices?

I would rather not cut down the picture quality more than I have done unless it is absolutely necessary. Is it possible to just load first image or the first three or something like that, and then load the others?

I´m using `umbraco` and `.mvc` razor to loop through the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{

    var mediaID1 = Model.Content.GetProperty("images").Value.ToString().Split(',');
    @:jQuery(function($){
    @:$.supersized({
        @:slideshow         :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
        @:autoplay          :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        @:start_slide       :   0,          // Start slide (0 is random)
        @:slide_interval    : 3000,              // Length between transitions
        @:fit_always        :0,
        @: slides: [
                     foreach (var mediaID in mediaID1){
            var media = umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia(mediaID);

    @:{ image: '@media.GetImageUrl()'},
             }
@:],
                      @:});
 @:});
}
```

My website: [www.jonasfotograf.se](http://www.jonasfotograf.se)

EDIT: I added a new field in umbraco where I upload pictures with max width 400px and I only have 5 images there, which I load when the width is less than 400px. However, I probably have reduced the quality of the images a bit too much, but what else do you think about this solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 460px)").matches)
{
    @{


      var mediaID5 = Model.Content.GetProperty("mobileimages").Value.ToString().Split(',');
    @:jQuery(function($){
                @:$.supersized({
                        @:slideshow         :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                        @:autoplay          :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                        @:start_slide       :   0,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                        @:slide_interval    : 3000,              // Length between transitions
                        @:fit_always        :0,
                        @: slides: [
                                     foreach (var mediaID in mediaID5){
            var media = umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia(mediaID);

    @:{ image: '@media.GetImageUrl()'},
                             }
@:],
                                      @:});
             @:});
                 }
}
else
@{


    var mediaID1 = Model.Content.GetProperty("images").Value.ToString().Split(',');
    @:jQuery(function($){
        @:$.supersized({
            @:slideshow         :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
        @:autoplay          :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        @:start_slide       :   0,          // Start slide (0 is random)
        @:slide_interval    : 3000,              // Length between transitions
        @:fit_always        :0,
        @: slides: [
                     foreach (var mediaID in mediaID1){
            var media = umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia(mediaID);

        @:{ image: '@media.GetImageUrl()'},
        }
@:],
    @:});
 @:});
}
```

Thanks to helping me in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to consider removing the slider all together for mobile devices. Especially people on their phone won't be to keen on this. Tablets are a different story though.

Comment: Not sure this can work for you but one thing to look into might be using media queries in JavaScript using `window.matchMedia`. That way you can load a different set of images per size-range. You don't have to cover all sizes for all devices but simply specify 2-3 set of ranges to cover them.

Comment: Big images will load slow on mobile devices and cause performance problems, you should prepare some smaller versions of your images and detect user's screen resolution and load appropriate images. Aside from lower mobile devices performance in general (processing, memory) you deal with lower bandwidth issues.

Comment: And yes you can preload images in background, but imho the size of images and processing required is the issue here. Preloading is basicly loading an image to a hidden dom element (css_hidden:{position:absolute; top:-99999px, left -99999px}), this way the images are loaded, cached, and can be reused, or you can just use the hidden elements to swap the images when you want to.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to keep different set of images for different devices for better performance

Comment: I edit my original post and wrote: 
EDIT: I added a new field in umbraco where I upload pictures with max width 400px and I only have 5 images there, which I load when the width is less than 400px. However, I probably have reduced the quality of the images a bit too much, but what else do you think about this solution?